# Extjs4 boxselect's displayfield issue

Tags: extjs4

i am working in extjs4. I have comboBox with store attached to it.

```
var store=Ext.create('ListStore',{
            model: 'ListModel',
            autoLoad:false,
            pageSize: 0
        });
```

i have binded this store to boxselectas=

```
xtype: 'boxselect',
                    height: 30,
                    store:store,
                    allowBlank: false,
                    displayField: 'name',
```

I have model with fields as =

```
{name: 'projectNumber', type: 'int'},
         {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
```

i want to show combo box text as ="name - ". So how to add displayfield to boxselect as required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `xtype: 'boxselect'` is, but for `xtype: 'combo'` you can use the `tpl` property:

```
    xtype: 'boxselect',
    height: 30,
    store:store,
    allowBlank: false,
    displayField: 'name',
    //...
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for="."><div class="x-boundlist-item" >{name} -  {projectNumber}</div></tpl>'),
    displayTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for=".">{name} -  {projectNumber}</tpl>')
```

Here is an example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/laurenzonneveld/pgYMZ/2/